# What are the spawn points for the "I Like My Monsters Rare" quest?

Tags: borderlands-2

> Objectives
>
> - Kill pink boroks: 0/8
> - Kill tailless scaylion: 0/8
> - Kill two-legged drifters: 0/6
> - Kill albino skags: 0/5
> - Kill slagged spores: 0/4

I've read that these monsters' spawns are completely random, but I know that at least some of the types have a proclivity for a certain area. (E.g., pink boroks in first valley of Adorton Station, albino skags with Claptrap's urine quest.) They aren't listed in the wiki. Where are the best places to find each of these?

Comment: I know two legged drifters can spawn around Hammerlocks lodge

Comment: I did not notice any significant probability bumps (not mentioning samples are too small to tell for sure). Where did you learn about that urine quest being more advantageous?

Comment: @OrcJMR: I got 4/5 of my albino skags there, as have others [(1)](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638785-borderlands-2/65212246)[(2)](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?s=777c83627ad7a0ff07ef57d8cd5f8ae2&p=3519146&postcount=10)

Comment: Ah, sorry, reading fail. Of course the area itself is good, as there are lots of skags there. I've assumed you mean the quest lends to albino population :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no specific factors that influence rare creature spawning, so the answer is just "anywhere lots of base creatures spawn". Here's a list of creatures' affinities to areas of Aegrus:

- Drifters: Hunter's Grotto, right around the Lodge.
- Spores: Hunter's Grotto, Ardorton Station, Candlerakk's Crag open areas.
- Boroks: Hunter's Grotto west and south-east, use elevator, Ardorton station west.
- Skags: Scylla's Grove mid-south, Ardorton Station center.
- Scaylions: Scylla's Grove north and west tunnels, Ardorton Station north and east, southwest path of Candlerakk's Crag.

Suggested farming areas would then be: Hunter's Grotto for spores, drifters, and boroks, Candlerakk's Crag for scaylions, and Scylla's Grove for skags. If farming for boroks, it may be effective to start at the Lodge, run through Scylla's Grove to Ardorton, reload there and head back.